# Why is the TAC-TRANSPNDR so important?

Tags: armada

What is so important about the TAC-TRANSPNDR Zach's dad pulls out of the manned Interceptor's hulls? He says it is important, but shows no reason why. Why is it so important if he has to rip apart the ship to pull it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transponder, by its nature, sends a signal indicating identity and location. We saw an earlier scene where Zack's transponder was what allowed the alien ship to get into the base and blow up a substantial amount of the ships. In this case, I believe that Zack's father intended the removal of the transponder to prevent them from being tracked by Admiral Vance.

Comment: Hah! I thought that might be it, but I thought it was just so that kind of mistake would not happen again. -_-